# Deserialize into another class - Spring data redis

Tags: serialization, json-deserialization, spring-data-redis

Working on **Spring Data Redis** I serialize an object and store it into Redis. The serialization strategy is `Jackson2JsonRedisSerializer`. So, suppose my bean is `Sample.java` with some properties `prop1, prop2` below is how it is added into the cache

```
\xAC\xED\x00\x05sr\x00'com.main.model.Sample\x90\x91\xFB4\xDD\x9D\xE1\xBB\x02\x00\x11J\x00\x0Bprop1J\x00\x0Aprop2J
```

As we can see the object type info `Sample` is also stored with its fully qualified name.

Now there are multiple services which work on this entry by deserializing and updating it writing back into cache. ***(The models/beans in various services have different fully qualified names)***

The problem occurs when a different service tries to deserialize it failing with `ClassNotFoundException`

```
    org.springframework.data.redis.serializer.SerializationException:         
       Cannot serialize; nested exception is 
       org.springframework.core.serializer.support.SerializationFailedException: 
       Failed to deserialize object type; 
       nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.xyz.model.BasicSample
```

Here is a sample

**Service 1**

```
    @Override
    @Cacheable(value = "sample", key = "{ #sample.sampleId }", unless = "#result == null")
    public Sample fetchSample(Sample sample) {...}
```

**Service 2**

```
    @Override
    @Cacheable(value = "sample", key = "{ #sample.sampleId }", unless = "#result == null")
    public BasicSample fetchBasicSample(BasicSample sample) {...}
```

Is there a way to either

- Stop storing this info
- Ignore this while deserialization
- A way to deserialize into a different class object with same properties

Comment: looking at the example data stored in Redis this does not look Jackson serialized, but more like the default jdk serialization. Can you check your `RedisCacheConfiguration` which should have something like `...serializeValuesWith(SerializationPair.fromSerializer(RedisSerializer.json()))`

Comment: @ChristophStrobl Right! The default serializer which Spring Data Redis uses is `Jackson2JsonRedisSerializer` which internally uses jdk serialization.

Comment: do you have a sample to run. The Jackson serializer uses `ObjectMapper.writeValuesAsBytes` directly. So the entry in Redis should be plain JSON something like `{"@class":"com.xyz.model.Sample","firstame":"calmity",...`
Do you have a snippet/gist/repo to run?

Answer (score 2):

I just spent half a day on the same issue so leaving the answer here for the future generations:

Generally, the Spring Data Redis will use the full class name for the _class key, but the dev can customize it with a `@TypeAlias("someAlias")` annotation. This will override the _class field.

Thus you can define the two classes as:

```
package com.example.service1;

import org.springframework.data.annotation.TypeAlias;
import org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisHash;
import org.springframework.data.redis.core.index.Indexed;

@RedisHash(value = "sample")
@TypeAlias("SampleType")
public class Sample {
    @Indexed
    int id;

    String name;
    ...
}
```

```
package com.example.service2;

import org.springframework.data.annotation.TypeAlias;
import org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisHash;
import org.springframework.data.redis.core.index.Indexed;

@RedisHash(value = "sample")
@TypeAlias("SampleType")
public class Sample {
    @Indexed
    int id;

    String name;
    ...
}
```

Now the redis object will be deserialized independently of the classes package name.

[Link to the relevant documentation for more info](https://www.docs4dev.com/docs/en/spring-data-redis/1.8.18.RELEASE/reference/all.html#_customizing_type_mapping)

Comment: Appreciate your effort :) Will give it a try.